# Multiple IF statements in Excel with search func

Tags: excel, if-statement

The function gave me a `#VALUE!` on the last "if", please let me know what is the problem.
The 2 first if's gave me the right answer.

```
IF(K20="CONV SUMMARY ROW","Cost",IF(SEARCH("open",K20),"Install",IF(SEARCH("depositor",K20),"Depositors")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may rephrase your formula as this:

```
=IF(K20="CONV SUMMARY ROW", "Cost", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("open", K20)), "Install",
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("depositor", K20)), "Depositors", "")))
```

ExcelJet [recommends](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text) wrapping calls to `SEARCH` with `ISNUMBER` to check if the searches were successful or not.  Besides this, the immediate problem with your formula is probably that the final `IF` does not have an else condition.  In the formula I gave above, I just use empty string if none of the conditions match.  But, if you just wanted to retain the original value of `K20`, you could replace the empty string with `K20`.